# Python print status lines: orphaned characters from previous print at the end

Tags: python

I want to write status messages with coloured status strings in python. It is supposed to look a bit like in Linux at the boot time.
Example:

`[status] Do something`

The status can be updated by calling a member of the Print_status() member.
Here's some example code:

```
import sys, time


class Print_status():
    """Prefix a unix like coloured status before printing a string.\n
    status : [wait, failed, ok]\n
    text : string to be printed after status
    single : Is text a one-liner [True] or shall it become updateable [False]?
    """
    __status_colors = {'ok' : '\033[32;1m', # bright green
                       'failed' : '\033[31;1m', # bright red
                       'wait' : '\033[33;1m', # orange
                       'blue' : '\033[34;1m'} # blue
    def __init__(self, text, status, single=False):
        """Constructor """
        self.text = text
        self.stat = status
        if single:
            self.output(self.text, self.stat, carriageret=False, newline=True)
        else:
            self.output(self.text, self.stat, carriageret=True, newline=False)

    def _get_color(self, stat):
        try:
            c = self.__status_colors[stat]
        except KeyError:
            c = '\033[0;1m' # black
        return c

    def output(self, text=False, status=False, carriageret=False, newline=False):
        """The first print of an updateable string or update an existing instance
        text : if given, the text can be changed
        status : if given, enter a new status here
        carriageret : Do a carriage return at the beginning (True for updateing text)
        newline : append a new line at the end (True for last status)
        """
        if not text:
            text = self.text
        if not status:
            status = self.stat
        col = self._get_color(status)
        if carriageret == True:
            cr = '\r'
        else:
            cr = ''
        if newline == True:
            nl = '\n'
        else:
            nl = ' '
        s = (cr + "[" + col + status + '\033[0m' + "] " + text + nl)
        # print(s, end='')
        sys.stdout.write(s)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def last(self, text=False, status=False):
        self.output(text, status, carriageret=True, newline=True)
        del self.text
        del self.stat

    def update(self, text=False, status=False):
        self.output(text, status, carriageret=True, newline=False)


p = Print_status("Teste die Ausgabe".format(), 'failed')
time.sleep(1)
p.update(status='wait')
time.sleep(1)
p.last(status='ok')
```

When I execute the script in booth, Powershell or my Spyder IDE I find rests of the previous statement at the end of the new status. (To reproduce this I construced the example so, that the text gets shorter each time)

Output:

```
[failed]Teste die Ausgabe
[wait]Teste die Ausgabe e
[ok]Teste die Ausgabebe e
```

How can I clear the buffer so that the new text if free of characters from the previos string?

Comment: You could just overwrite the rest of the line with spaces.

Comment: Yes, this is a quick and dirty fix. I am looking for the cause and a fix for the problem and not the symptoms only.

Comment: The cause is that you just overwrite a few of the characters and the fix is to overwrite all the characters. `\r` does not erase the last line, it just resets the caret to the start of the line.

Comment: If you don't like the cursor being way after the end of the string, you could also reset the caret, then write a whole line of spaces, then reset the caret again and finally write the new, possibly shorter line.

Comment: Got it. I expected another behaviour on \r but now I see, that there is no other solution without massive increase of complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to just [ljust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to add padding to your string.
That will ensure your overwrite any buffer remaining of the previous write.

```py
>>> 'bla'.ljust(100)
'bla                                                                                                 '
```